# How to measure the exact performance (time taken to execute) of a binary which is taking input from user

Tags: c, performance, unix, hp-ux

I have a C program written in such a way that it takes a file name as input to read. Now the problem is i am using time/timex command on HPUX to know the exact performance or time elapsed during the complete execution of the program.

The problem is, i am not able to get the exact performance by these time/timex command due to the time taken during the input insertion for that program. time/timex command is also considering the time taken by the user to provide the input.

Can anyone please help me as to how should i measure the actual performance in such case where user is giving input which is required to run the program ?

Answer (score 1):

`time` reports both the real time and CPU time. The real time includes time spent waiting for input, but the CPU time (user + sys) should give you just the time actually spent by your program performing computations.

Comment: in my case time gives the output like real  7.7 user 0.0 sys 0.0 i want to know the exact figure which is elapsed during execution.

Comment: @Goldi: Then it effectively took 0 seconds (i.e. less than the resolution of your system clock). You'll have to run it with a much larger input to see non-zero values.